# How do I integrate Boost into a Visual C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I'm trying to link up some of the boost stuff with a visual C++ project of mine and am not sure what the best way to do this is, I'm specifically interested in the singleton class.

Comment: Boost (version 1.40) doesn't provide a singleton class, although there are a couple of restricted ones scattered around in "details" namespaces.

Comment: You're better off avoiding singletons in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to RTFM but Boost [Getting Started on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) is the first place to go.

As you can see from the TOC, it is a very coherent walkthrough.

> 1. Get Boost
> 2. The Boost Distribution
> 3. Header-Only Libraries
> 4. Build a Simple Program Using Boost
>
>    1. Build From the Visual Studio IDE
>    2. Or, Build From the Command Prompt
>    3. Errors and Warnings

Answer (score 2):

You need to download boost libraries, build them. Then link against the libraries you want, and add boost directory to your additional include headers.

THis link from boost is helpful: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Answer (score 2):

- you can download an installer from boostpro (http://www.boostpro.com/download). It's not always the latest version but it's well done and you can choose what you need. It's already pre-built with all possible options.
- add the boost headers (for example myboostpath\boost\boost_1_39) in VC++ Directories/include
- add the boost libs (for example ma_boost_path\boost\boost_1_39\lib) in VC++ Directories/Library Files

But I don't know of any Singleton, at least as top-level library.

Comment: Boostpro do not have msvc10 builds yet.

Answer (score 1):

Most of boost is headers only and all you have to do is

> 1. Download boost
> 2. Move them to your include folder in visual c++
> 3. Include the wanted headers:

```
//Your headers of choice
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
```

This obviously doesn't work with headers you need to compile, you have the other answers for that, and I'm not familiar with any Singleton class.